# CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to run Karma in Netbeans 8 on Windows 7 following "Learning AngularJS" Ken Williamson early release in Chapter 4.

Here is the IDE log section:

```
 java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32      application
     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
   Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program     "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-cli\bin\karma" (in directory "C:\Users\...\jee6withNetbeans7\AngularJsHelloWorld_chapter4"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you have `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin\karma.cmd` this file?

Comment: Hi Rebomix: there is a karma file there, but the properties are described only as file, no .cmd extension. And the book had us download karma-cli and use the cli instead, and in \bin, the same karma file has no cmd or exe extension

Comment: Does this help? http://www.fixcodeerror.com/error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application